# What can we say about $\dim \operatorname{null}(AB)$ from knowing $p_A$ and $p_B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Say, there are two matrices $A, B \in \mathbb R^{3,3} $ such that their characteristic polynomials are $p_A(t) = t^3 − t^2 + 2t$ and $p_B(t) = t^3 − 7t^2 + 9t − 3$. What do we know about $\dim \operatorname{null}(AB)$?

Clearly, $t=0$ is one of the roots of $p_A$ so $A$ is singular, and therefore $AB$ is singular too. So $\dim \operatorname{null}(AB) \geq 1$. Is there anything else we can conclude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a little more we know. $p_B(0) \neq 0$, so $B$ is bijective, and hence $\dim \operatorname{null}(AB) = \dim \operatorname{null} (A)$. Further, $p_A(t) = t(t^2-t+2)$ has three distinct roots (one real, two conjugate complex), so $\dim \operatorname{null} (A) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of (the linear map associated to) a matrix is its eigenspace for$~0$ (taken to be $\{0\}$ in case $0$ is not an eigenvalue) and its dimension is less than or equal to the multiplicity of$~0$ as root of the characteristic polynomial. For $A$ this multiplicity is$~1$, for $B$ it is$~0$. Then the kernel of $AB$ then can have dimension at most $1+0=1$. You already argued that it is also at least$~1$.